# Data Structure of Wordpress' get_posts function?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working with Wordpress, and trying to get the information from all the posts created the current day. My code currently looks like this:

```
        $today = getdate();
 $posts = get_posts('year=' .$today["year"] .'&monthnum=' .$today["mon"] .'&day=' .$today["mday"] );

 $CurrentPost = array($posts[0]);

 $Post_Date = $CurrentPost[post_date];
 echo "Post Date: $Post_Date ";
```

However, I am getting NULL for Post Date. Am I accessing the data structure correctly? I know that there is data there, because when I do a print_r on the $posts array, I get the following:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 4 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2011-01-01 02:59:09 [post_date_gmt] => 2011-01-01 02:59:09 [post_content] => This Post created Friday December 31st, 2010 [post_title] => Test Post 1 [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => open [ping_status] => open [post_password] => [post_name] => test-post-1 [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2011-01-01 02:59:09 [post_modified_gmt] => 2011-01-01 02:59:09 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] => http://localhost/wordpress/?p=4 [menu_order] => 0 [post_type] => post [post_mime_type] => [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 1 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2011-01-01 02:43:02 [post_date_gmt] => 2011-01-01 02:43:02 [post_content] => Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging! [post_title] => Hello world! [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => open [ping_status] => open [post_password] => [post_name] => hello-world [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2011-01-01 02:43:02 [post_modified_gmt] => 2011-01-01 02:43:02 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] => http://localhost/wordpress/?p=1 [menu_order] => 0 [post_type] => post [post_mime_type] => [comment_count] => 1 [filter] => raw ) )
```

I would like to be able to just access each element in each post directly as if calling it from an array so I can generate a non-html output of the posts written the current day. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:
So I tried this out. Both of these work for me:

```
echo "Post Date 1: " .$posts[0]->post_date . "<br/>";
echo "Post Date 2: " . mysql2date('M j Y', $posts[0]->post_date);
```

Here is my output:

```
Post Date 1: 2011-01-01 01:45:40
Post Date 2: Jan 1 2011
```

Comment: I just edited my answer. The code works for me - I put it into archive.php on my personal blog. and ran it.

Comment: My bad. I just realized that I'm clearing the information by attempting to convert it to an array. It works for me now. Thanks!!

Comment: No you are not clearing it - but it is not doing what you expected. The object $posts[0] will be the first element of your $CurrentPost array. If you want to retrieve it from the $CurrentPost object itself, you can get it like this: $CurrentPost[0]->post_date)

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to access the data as an array, when it is an object.
instead of:

```
$Post_Date = $CurrentPost[post_date];
```

use:

```
$Post_Date = $CurrentPost->post_date;
```